# Can I define a new key for Meteor.users Collection?

Tags: meteor

I want to add more functionality to the users collection. For example:

```
user.priviledges = ['admin']
```

or anything else...

Comment: Check out the roles Atmosphere package: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: I've used that actually, lol. I just realized I could actually dive into the code and see how they do it -- but I think they just use a different Collection entirely to keep track of permissions...

Comment: They use a roles collection as well as storing roles on user documents.

Comment: You can also add anything you like to documents in the `Meteor.users` collection, like you would any other Meteor collection if you want to do something more add hoc.  I suppose there's the potential for conflict with Meteor's default functionality, but I've not had any problems when adding sub-keys to users' `profile` keys in a limited way.

Comment: `priviledges` -> `privileges`

Comment: Re: meteor-roles, the 'roles' collection is purely a convenience for seeing the complete list of roles that have been added.  I've often considered removing it as it tends to be a source of confusion.  The important info is all stored in a 'roles' field on the user object.  Also, even though the name of the package is meteor-roles, you can just as easily assign finer-grained permissions like 'check-in' or 'edit-post'.  To the package, its all just strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it when registering a new user.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    user.profile    = {
        name    : "Ugur",
        surname : "Toprakdeviren",
                    sex     : true
    };

   return user;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just run it as you would with `Meteor.users`

For instance for the user with id `1234`

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: '1234'}, {$set: {priviledges: ['admin'] } });
```

Be sure to set `.allow` rules if you're doing this from the client.

But as mentioned in the comments the best for these role type properties use the meteor-roles package on atmosphere.

Comment: `priviledges` -> `privileges`

Comment: just sticking to what the question had, was aware of the spelling. Also i'm not too sure the correct spelling adds any value or weight the meaning is understood

Comment: Fair enough.  Bad spelling just makes me twitchy.